# Terraform - Error: [DEBUG] Create SSH Key illegal base64 data at input byte 1

Tags: cloud, websphere, terraform

I'm trying to run the below code on IBM cloud to provision different resources, all of them get created but the VSI/VM instance is having issues with the public key but not sure whats going on, **here is the code test.tf:**

```
# Configure the IBM Cloud Provider
provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key      = "${var.ibmcloud_api_key}"
  generation            = 2
  region                = "us-south"

}



###################Reources###################

#VPC
resource "ibm_is_vpc" "vpc1" {
  name                  = "vpc1"
}


#Subnet for the VPC
resource "ibm_is_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name            = "subnet1"
  vpc             = ibm_is_vpc.vpc1.id
  zone            = "${var.zone1}"
  ipv4_cidr_block = "10.240.0.0/24"
}


#Second Subnet for bastion VSI
resource "ibm_is_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name            = "subnet2"
  vpc             = ibm_is_vpc.vpc1.id
  zone            = "${var.zone1}"
  ipv4_cidr_block = "10.240.1.0/24"
  public_gateway = "${ibm_is_public_gateway.gateway.id}"
}


#Public Gateway
resource "ibm_is_public_gateway" "gateway" {
  name = "gateway"
  vpc  = ibm_is_vpc.vpc1.id
  zone = "${var.zone1}"
}


#data SSH
resource "ibm_is_ssh_key" "ssh_public_key" {
    name = "testssh"
    public_key = var.ssh_public_key
}


#VSI

resource "ibm_is_instance" "vm1" {
  name              = "vm1"
  image             = "${var.image}"
  profile           = "${var.profile}"
  zone              = "${var.zone1}"
  keys              = [ibm_is_ssh_key.ssh_public_key.id]
  vpc               = ibm_is_vpc.vpc1.id

  primary_network_interface {
    subnet          = ibm_is_subnet.subnet2.id
  }

  network_interfaces {
    name            = "eth1"
    subnet          = ibm_is_subnet.subnet2.id

  }

  }
```

**Here is the variables file variables.tf:**

```
#variables

#API Key top connect to my IBM Cloud
variable "ibmcloud_api_key" {
    default = "9lsRdBjb70PlwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxLdf6"
}


##What zone I want to use
#IBMcloud regions would help to get the regions/zones
variable "zone1" {
    default = "us-south-1"

}


#SVSI image template
#ibmcloud is image command
variable "image" {
    default = "6aec77ca-ab4a-459e-81dc-6e5ec9f99d4a" #centos minimal

}


#SSH key for the VMs/VSIs for provisioning
variable "ssh_public_key" {
    default = "C:/Users/User.Name/ibmkey.pub"

}


#VSI config
#ibmcloud is instance-profiles command
variable "profile" {
    default = "bc1-2x8" #2CPUs and 8GB of RAM

}
```

**Here is the Error output after running apply:**

```
Error: [DEBUG] Create SSH Key illegal base64 data at input byte 1
{
    "StatusCode": 400,
    "Headers": {
        "Cache-Control": [
            "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        ],
        "Cf-Cache-Status": [
            "DYNAMIC"
        ],
        "Cf-Ray": [
            "5b8ab320e9c4b959-MIA"
        ],
        "Cf-Request-Id": [
            "042a8e48910000b959aa8fe200000001"
        ],
        "Connection": [
            "keep-alive"
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
            "187"
        ],
        "Content-Security-Policy": [
            "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        ],
        "Date": [
            "Sun, 26 Jul 2020 02:30:37 GMT"
        ],
        "Expect-Ct": [
            "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
        ],
        "Expires": [
            "-1"
        ],
        "Pragma": [
            "no-cache"
        ],
        "Server": [
            "cloudflare"
        ],
        "Set-Cookie": [
            "__cfduid=dab8eaaa41dc1d2e24658e3191d0e3d881595730636; expires=Tue, 25-Aug-20 02:30:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.iaas.cloud.ibm.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure"
        ],
        "Strict-Transport-Security": [
            "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
        ],
        "Vary": [
            "Accept-Encoding"
        ],
        "X-Content-Type-Options": [
            "nosniff"
        ],
        "X-Request-Id": [
            "7ff3ada5-02e8-4fb2-a1f2-5fa9ca4da415"
        ],
        "X-Trace-Id": [
            "7108b437f9d18820"
        ],
        "X-Xss-Protection": [
            "1; mode=block"
        ]
    },
    "Result": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": "key_parse_failure",
                "message": "illegal base64 data at input byte 1",
                "target": {
                    "name": "key.public_key",
                    "type": "field"
                }
            }
        ],
        "trace": "7ff3ada5-02e8-4fb2-a1f2-5fa9ca4da415"
    },
    "RawResult": null
}


  on test1.tf line 51, in resource "ibm_is_ssh_key" "ssh_public_key":
  51: resource "ibm_is_ssh_key" "ssh_public_key" {
```

Any idea???

Comment: I have been googling but could not find any reference to the error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that you're specifying your SSH public key as a filename rather than as an actual public key definition, so the provider is sending the literal string `C:/Users/User.Name/ibmkey.pub` as your key, rather than the contents of that file.

I'm not familiar enough with this provider to be sure, but I think it is expecting you to already have read that file and to pass its *content* as the `public_key` argument of `ibm_is_ssh_key`.

The two main options for how to proceed here would be to either pass the content of the file when you set the `ssh_public_key` variable, making it the caller's responsibility to read the file into memory first, or to change your module to read the given file into memory itself:

```
resource "ibm_is_ssh_key" "ssh_public_key" {
    name       = "testssh"
    public_key = file(var.ssh_public_key)
}
```

[According to the provider source code](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/terraform-provider-ibm/blob/25fc02c6e3a938a1e702eaefe63bf0f5a1587ec6/ibm/resource_ibm_is_ssh_key.go#L158), most of this error message is being returned directly from the remote API, so if reading the file also doesn't work you may need to consult the documentation for this `POST /keys` API operation to learn what format it is expecting for its `key.public_key` argument, and then match that format in your Terraform configuration.

Comment: I did paste the file contento directly in the argument and it worked so yes I needed the "file()" in order to open the file properly. Thanks Martin!